# GPS Software for OSM data gathering

Tags: gps, garmin

I recently unearthed a GPS unit I purchased a few years. It's a Garmin GPSmap 60 ([picture](http://www.moshannonfalls.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/garminwaterproofgpsmap60.jpg)) and has a usb port on it. Is there a way that I can link it to my mac? I do have windows installed also, and could use that if necessary.

I tried plugging it in, and downloading data via google earth pro without success. I also hunted around online to see what I should install but did know what I was searching for exactly (a driver? a software program? ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GPS Babel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) is your friend for all 'consumer grade' GPS units.  Download, convert, transfer etc. all from one program!  You can also use it from within QGIS as a plugin as well.

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly and has an incredible range of file-format outputs.

Answer (score 2):

When I worked for Navigon the way we accessed the filesystem on the devices which were running Windows Mobile 5 was to put a text file with a particular name on the root of the SD card / USB, and it had a weird name like win.reg or something like that, and plugging it in would give you a windows file explorer instead of the standard device boot sequence / updating the maps progress bar. The file was empty it was the filename that mattered.  I wanna say it was win.reg but I am probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try the DNRGarmin GPS Application: http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html

Answer (score 1):

For Apple Mac - http://www.gpsy.com/features.html

Download GPSy X 3.41 with Garmin **USB** Support

Note: **Mac OS X Intel Only**, not compatible with PowerPC-based Macs

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [someone](http://ansi.interblc.com/tag/garmin/) has already found a way to play with the Garmin GPSmap 60 in a UNIX environment using GPS Babel (as [Darren Cope](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/how-do-i-find-software-for-my-gps/3204#3204) suggested).

Another option is trying to use Garmin software:

- [Garmin Communicator](http://www8.garmin.com/products/communicator/) browser plugin,
- [Garmin Connect](http://connect.garmin.com/help/start) web service, or the
- [Garmin Device Interface SDK](http://developer.garmin.com/web-device/device-sdk)